# Code 500 internal Server error when posting to user: sendMail (microsoft Graph-API)

Tags: python, python-requests, microsoft-graph-api

I get a Status Code 500 error when attempting to post to the [user: sendMail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) endpoint (JSON format):

```
JSON Response  {'error': {'code': 'ErrorInternalServerError', 'message': 'An internal server error occurred. The operation failed.'}}
SystemExit: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/myemail@contoso.com/sendMail
```

- Using this method of authenticating to a different endpoint(https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/) works as expected.
- Posting the json directly into the [Graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) sends the mail as expected

I'm unsure how to bugfix this error 500, I can't seem to find any entries in entra>Identity>Monitoring&Health>Audit logs , any suggestions?

Code:

```
import json
import msal
import requests
'''
Sjabloonscript 26-9-23 Graph API
Zie https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer voor typen eindpunten
'''
#send from?
versturende_email = "myemail@contoso.com"
#demomode?
demo = True
#config
config = {
        "client_id": "------",
        "scope": ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"],
        "secret": "SECRETHERE",
        "tenant-id": "tenid",
        "authority": 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/-----',
        "eindpunt": 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/'+versturende_email+'/sendMail'
    }

def O365_toegangstoken():
    '''
    Haal toegangstoken op met je app registratie , let op de duur van de token
    '''
    #Get token
    scopes = ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"]
    app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
        config["client_id"],
        authority=config["authority"],
        client_credential=config["secret"],
    )
    # Since MSAL 1.23, acquire_token_for_client(...) will automatically look up
    # a token from cache, and fall back to acquire a fresh token when needed.
    resultaat = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=config["scope"])
    #check if token was returned
    if "access_token" in resultaat:
              toegangstoken = 'Bearer ' + resultaat['access_token']
              return toegangstoken
    else:
        print(result.get("error"))
        print(result.get("error_description"))
        print(result.get("correlation_id"))  # Nodig voor als je een bug wil rapporteren
        raise Exception("Tokenerrrrror")


def main():
    #get token
    token = O365_toegangstoken()
    #headers
    hoofd = {
      'Authorization': token
    }
    #de toegangstoken is goed gegenereerd
    #generate mail json
    mailbericht = {}
    html = """
    <html>
      <head></head>
      <body>
        <p>Beste {0},<br><br>
           blablatestmessage
           {2}{3}
           <b>Let op!</b> blablabla
           <br><br>
           <i>Dit betreft een automatisch gegenereerd bericht</i>
           <br><br>
           Met vriendelijke groet,
           <br><br>
           Automatisering.
        </p>
        {4}
      </body>
    </html>
    """.replace("\n", "")
    mailbericht["message"] = {
        'subject' : 'Hallo',
        'body' : {
            'contentType' : 'HTML',
            'content' : html
        }
    }
    mailbericht["message"]['toRecipients'] = []
    mailbericht["message"]['toRecipients'].append({'emailAddress': {
        "address": naar
    }})
    #print json and header?
    if demo:
         print("{0}\n{0}Header{0}\n{2}\n{0}\n{1}\n{0}".format("-"*50,json.dumps(mailbericht,indent=5),hoofd))
    try:
        #post to graph
        r = requests.post(url= config["eindpunt"], headers=hoofd, json = json.dumps(mailbericht))
        r.raise_for_status()
        #error handling
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
        print("Status Code", r.status_code)
        print("JSON Response ", r.json())
        raise SystemExit(err)

    #non-error handling
    print("Status Code", r.status_code)
    print("JSON Response ", r.json())
        
main()
```

Comment: The codes in the 5xx area are server errors, meaning there is a problem on their systems, it can be a direct or indirect cause of something you did differently than they expect though.

Comment: Thanks @KlausD. I've opened a ticket with microsoft support - I'll be sure to update here when I learn more.